# Asp.net Core EF Core Inner Join, and data to View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, inner-join, ef-core-2.0

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    AppointmentsViewModel appointmentsViewModel = new AppointmentsViewModel();

      var ap = await (from p in _context.Mstr_Patients
              join e in _context.Appointments on p.PatientID equals e.PatientID
              select new { No = e.AppointmentNo, Date = e.AppointmentDate, Name = p.FullName, Ref = e.RefDoctor }).ToListAsync();



    return View(ap);
}
```

```
public class AppointmentsViewModel
{
    public int No { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ref { get; set; }
}
```

How do I bind my data from the inner join to the ViewModel class, so I can display it on a view?

I've tried `ap = appointmentsViewModel;`  but it gives me an error. How do I do that?

Comment: Select new AppointmentsViewModel

Comment: @MartijnWoudstra could u please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select `AppointmentsViewModel` instead of [`anonymous type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) as following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
      var ap = await (from p in _context.Mstr_Patients
                      join e in _context.Appointments on p.PatientID equals e.PatientID
                      select new AppointmentsViewModel
                                { 
                                    No = e.AppointmentNo, 
                                    Date = e.AppointmentDate, 
                                    Name = p.FullName, 
                                    Ref = e.RefDoctor 
                                }).ToListAsync();


    return View(ap);
}
```